# Read annotations from PsiClass in intellij idea plugin

Tags: java, plugins, intellij-idea, annotations, intellij-plugin

I want to read annotations from PsiClass in intellij idea plugin development.. Is there any API for that. I am not able to do this with reflections as psiClass can't be converted to java.lang.Class

Comment: Sry I din't get you... there isn't any method to read annotations in PsiClass.class

Comment: Get the `Class` object for your class and use the relevant methods to get annotations.

Comment: sorry, but i already did that and it is throwing java.lang.ClassCastException

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to read annotations from the PsiClass with the help of "com.intellij.codeInsight.AnnotationUtil"http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.jetbrains/intellij-idea/12.0/com/intellij/codeInsight/AnnotationUtil.java...We can also try with this code :

```
PsiAnnotation[] annotation= modifierList.getAnnotations();
```

Answer (score 5):

```
PsiClass psiClass = ...;

PsiModifierList psiModifierList = psiClass.getModifierList();

PsiAnnotation[] annotations = psiModifierList.getAnnotations();
```